# Communication between two components using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble communicating between two components using React.

Here are the codes:

File `Search.js`:

```
const Search = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");

  const apiKey = "*********";

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    await fetch(
      `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${apiKey}&ipAddress=${input}`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        setItems(result);
      });
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="my-wrap">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="searchTerm"
          placeholder="Search for any IP adress or domain"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="searchButton">
          {" "}
          <img src={RightIcon} alt="icon" />{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

File `Results.js`:

```
const Results = (props) => {
  const { ip, city, country, postalCode, timezone, isp } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container2">
        <div className="container-pop">
          <div>
            <h2 className="title-span"> IP Address </h2>
            <p> {ip} </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 className="title-span"> Location </h2>

            <p>
              {city}, {country}
            </p>

            <p> {postalCode} </p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2 className="title-span"> Timezone </h2>
            <p> UTC {timezone} </p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2 className="title-span"> ISP </h2>
            <p> {isp} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

What I am not able to do is the communication between them, for example: I do the Google IP search 8.8.8.8, the console returns me all right with the information, but I can't pass this information to `Results.js`, to take them and print them on canvas. If I do it in the same component (`Search.js`) it comes out on the screen, but the styling of the CSS gets messy. Is there a way to make this communication between these two components?

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4eRn.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQuU.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Could you show a bit more code? How are you rendering the Results component, for example.

Comment: Option 1) Using props, pass the data up from `Search` to the closest parent component of both `Search` and `Result`, then pass the data down to `Result`. Option 2) Use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a state library like Redux to store your data independently from yoru components and consume it where needed. There is a lot of information on google about this if you search your question title.

Comment: @Slbox I added 2 images, the first as it is currently output, the second, as I want it to leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I can't be 100% sure here, but it looks like what you need to do is lift your `items` state to a parent of `<Search>` and `<Results>`

```
function SearchPage() {
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState([])
  return (
    <div>
      <Search onChange={setResults) />
      <div>
        {results.map((result) => <Results {...result} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And you'll need to change `Search.js`

```
const Search = (props) => {
  // New prop! This is a change handler passed from the parent
  const { onChange } = props
  // remove the results data from state here
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");

  const apiKey = "*********";

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    await fetch(
      `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${apiKey}&ipAddress=${input}`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        // Instead of setting state, we call the change handler function.
        onChange(result);
      });
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    // ... same return value
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Of course, you'll need to put this in the correct markup so that it's styled the way you'd like, but the important thing here is that we took the state from `Search` and we *lifted* it a common parent of both `Search` and `Results`. This is a very common technique in React. From the common parent, we can pass a change handler to `Search` so that we get the results of the API request after a user inputs something, and then we can set that as state to our parent component. From there, we can pass it down into Results. This is the way with React: data flows down as props, and you pass change handler functions as props to get data back up from child components.

```
<SearchPage> {/* <---- put the state at this level. the next highest above Search and Results, so you can pass change handlers and data (props) _down_ into the components. */}
  <Search />
  <Results />
  <Results />
  <Results />
  <Results />
</SearchPage>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for !! By making the call as you mentioned, I was able to get the API results to output display. Thank you!!